# HTML5 Drag & Drop 'dragover' event

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, html5-draggable

I'm building a web app with functionality that resembles the floating panel functionality of popular software like Adobe Photoshop or Illustrator. I'm using the HTML5 Drag & Drop API to do so.

First, to update the panel I'm dragging, I'm doing something along these lines

```
el.style.left = (x - offsetX) + 'px';
el.style.top = (y - offsetY) + 'px';
```

Now, this all works great! But the problem is that I want to catch the *dragover* event on another block element, like so

```
dropzone.addEventListener('dragover', function() { ... }, false);
```

The thing is, as long as I update my dragging element's position, the event *never* gets fired. But when I comment out the repositiong of my dragging element, the event *does* get fired, like so

```
// Commenting out the repositioning...

// el.style.left = (x - offsetX) + 'px';
// el.style.top = (y - offsetY) + 'px';
```

Now, to me this feels like the element I'm dragging sort of is *in the way* for the event to fire.

How do I keep dragging my block element around, but fire the *dragover* event aswell?

**Check out the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6bj2jmcf/1/)!**

Working in Chrome 36.0.1985.125

Thanks!

Comment: you're kinda mixing two types of dnd here: old-school element.style re-positioning, and html5 dnd events, which are more for dragging links, files and other non-elements to actionable drop targets. maybe if you setTimeout 1ms on the re-position, you might not interfere with the "undercarriage"

Comment: JSFiddle created, see edit